# How can I load a library in shared_addons from a shared_addons module in PyroCMS?

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, pyrocms

I'm making a module in the `./addons/shared_addons/modules/` directory. The module's called `render`.

From within that module I want to access a library that I've put in the `./addons/shared_addons/libraries/` directory. The library's called `pchart`

If, from the module, I use `$this->load->library('pchart')` it fails saying that it can't find the file.

I've tried copying the `pchart` library file to the `./system/cms/libraries/` directory, and from there it loads fine, so the file itself is OK. It's just not looking in the right place.

By default it's looking in the module for the library but it's not there. How can I tell PyroCMS to look in the right place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the PyroCMS forums (http://pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/5385) to find this out in the end:

The `./addons/shared_addons/libraries/` directory is used for sharing addons across all sites being managed by the one PyroCMS install.

In most cases there's just one site, `default`. In order to share an addon with the whole site there's a directory at `./addons/default/` that is the second port of call for the loader library. (second to the module itself)

Comment: If only this answered my question this time too :(